# Flask-babel: translation per user

Tags: python, flask

How can I translate a page with a specific language per user using Flask-Babel? I can translate all user pages setting: "app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'en'". How can I translate it per user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/#configuration:

```
from flask import g, request

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    # if a user is logged in, use the locale from the user settings
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is not None:
        return user.locale
    # otherwise try to guess the language from the user accept
    # header the browser transmits.  We support de/fr/en in this
    # example.  The best match wins.
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(['de', 'fr', 'en'])
```

You can get locale from User in database, from url, domain or subdomain, from user request headers. You can have own locale detection method, but you need return locale with `babel.localeselector`. If `babel.localeselector` can't get locale, then it use default locale in `BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE`.

When you get right locale, you also need create translates `.po` and `.mo` for each supported locale. Do not forget that each translated string must be marked as for translation.